# Android: Handle clicks on blank space in ScrollView

Tags: android, android-scrollview

In my Android application, there is a `ScrollView` containing a vertical `LinearLayout` that contains several views. `LinearLayout` has `layout_height = "wrap_content"`. It is possible that the `ScrollView` content takes up less space than is on the screen and creates empty space (`ScrollView` itself has `layout_height = "match_parent"`). I would like to handle clicks on this empty space. I tried to use `setOnClickListener` on a `ScrollView`, but my callback is not called.

Comment: Maybe set ScrollView to clickable?

Comment: @Epig Doesn't help

Comment: You can try it with an OnTouchListener or use a third LinearLayout which is set to match_parent to get thoose OnClick events.

Comment: Is there any reason for the empty space? I mean do you want an empty space there?

Comment: @UmangBurman sometimes my content is smaller than screen size. If you want to suggest adding to the `LinearLayout` in `ScrollView` the last element of the additional View to catch clicks, then this suits me. But I don’t know how to adjust the size of this `View` so that it only takes up extra space inside the ScrollView and does not add a constant indent from the bottom when scrolling.

Comment: Okay, I understand, Have you tried anything like this with `ConstraintLayout`? @kiv_apple

Comment: @UmangBurman What do you mean? As I understand it, `layout_height="match_parent"` does not work inside ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a callback on your `ScrollView`'s parent (say a `FrameLayout`) view:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/scrollViewContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:onClick="onBlankSpaceClick">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!-- continue... -->
```

Or attach the callback programatically:

```
scrollViewContainer.setOnClickListener(::onBlankSpaceClick)
```

Comment: It works only if `ScrollView` has `layout_height="wrap_content"`, but I want to use `layout_height="match_parent"` to use `overScrollMode="always"` and your solution doesn't work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to add a placeholder view at the bottom of your `LinearLayout` which fills empty space if there is any.

Ensure your `ScrollView` has `android:fillViewport="true"` set and that last placeholder view has `android:layout_height="match_parent"` set.

Something like this:

```
<ScrollView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fillViewport="true">

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    ... other views

    <View
      android:id="@+id/remainingScrollViewSpace"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

  </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Add an `onClickListener` on `remainingScrollViewSpace` if you want to get a click event on that "empty" space.